# Waiting until files are being created in Java

Tags: java, file, spring-boot

I'm working on a web API (with Spring Boot) that Convert a pdf using external C++ api, this program is working but when I want to send the file in the body response I get this error:

```
{
"timestamp": "2019-04-10T09:56:01.696+0000",
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "file [D:\\[Phenix-Monitor]1.pdf] cannot be resolved in the file system for checking its content length",
"path": "/convert/toLinPDf"}
```

The controller :

```
@PostMapping("/toLinPDf")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> convertion(@RequestParam(value = "input", required = false) String in,
        @RequestParam(value = "output", required = false) String out) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    linearizeService.LinearizePDf(in, out);
    FileSystemResource pdfFile = new FileSystemResource(out);
    return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
            .contentType(
                    MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(pdfFile.getInputStream())));

}
```

I guess that the problem is in the `linearizeService.LinearizePDf(in, out);` because in this method I'm using external process, so what is happening is that when I try to open the file with `FileSystemResource pdfFile = new FileSystemResource(out);`, the linearizeService did not finish processing yet that why I get this error, my question is: **how can I handle this, I mean how to wait for the file to be created then send this file ?**

Comment: you should try with `Future` API of Java 8

Comment: @HusamBdr , how can i use Future API in my case ?

Comment: Please see the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest that you use `Future API` of Java 8.

Here an update for your resource.

```
@PostMapping("/toLinPDf")
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> convertion(
    @RequestParam(value = "input", required = false) String in,
    @RequestParam(value = "output", required = false) String out) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Callable<String> callable = () -> {
        linearizeService.LinearizePDf(in, out);
        return "Task ended";
};
Future<String> future = executorService.submit(callable);
String result = future.get();
executorService.shutdown();
FileSystemResource pdfFile = new FileSystemResource(out);
return ResponseEntity
            .ok()
            .contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
            .contentType(
                    MediaType.parseMediaType("application/pdf"))
            .body(new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(pdfFile.getInputStream())));

}
```

Comment: This answer does not answer the question. This code returns immediately that `linearizeService.LinearizePDf()` returns, as does the OP's code. The OP states that LinearizePDf() continues to execute after the call returns and he wants advice as to how to synchronize with that behaviour. The OP has not provided enough information about the the linearizeService() API for the question to be answered.

Comment: I didn't understand you quite well, but I see that he wanted to wait for a task to be finished not to synchronize with it, there is a difference. For `linearizeService API`, it is obvious (since it is written with C++) that he uses `JNI` to run the C++ piece of code to generate his pdf. @Youssef could you please test the answer and confirm

Comment: Your code is functionally identical to his code. He executes his call and when it returns he reads the file. You spawn a thread, immediately block, make the call in the other thread, then read the file when the call returns. No difference. None at all.